# What use could I have for an invalid GIF on my site?

Tags: web-development, images

I have found a 1x1 GIF embedded directly in Google homepage's HTML:

[image: Screenshot of Google homepage source]

**How could I use such GIF on my site?**

To make it more interesting. I tried saving it through Chrome, then opening with GIMP, but it threw an error. Then I attempted to decode it with a [Python script](http://pastebin.com/w2vNC1D4), resulting file was identical as the one that Chrome created and it still didn't work.

So I tried to reverse engineer it with a hex editor. Here is what it contains according to [this](http://www.onicos.com/staff/iz/formats/gif.html) and [this](http://www.matthewflickinger.com/lab/whatsinagif/bits_and_bytes.asp) format description:

```
Offset      Value           Meaning
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x00        GIF89a          File format version
0x06        0x01000100      Image size: 1x1 px
0x0A        0x00            Packed byte: 1-bit 2-color palette,
                              no global color table
0x0B        0x00            Ignored without global color table
0x0C        0x00            Pixel aspect ratio 1:1
0x0D        0x2C            Beginning of image. Not 0x21 so no transparency
                              and no animation
0x0E        0x00000000      Image starts in top left corner
0x12        0x01000100      Image size: 1x1 px
0x16        0x00            Packed byte: no local color table, no interlacing
```

Offset 0x17 should contain image data which is missing, so the file is in fact invalid. I doubt that any program could output a 1x1 GIF which doesn't contain any pixels or even color tables, it was probably crafted manually for some reason.

**What's the point of embedding corrupted GIFs in `<img>` tags? What use could I have for it?**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not **[about a website you control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**.

Comment: @JohnConde Is there a SE site where I can ask this question? (BTW, [help/on-topic] could use some improvement. The title is *What topics **can** I ask about here?* and it contains a list of topics you **should not** ask about. It's confusing. [Welcome on Meta](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/1249) doesn't help much too, my question fits under the second bullet yet it's apparently off-topic.)

Comment: I think this is a good question and I would be interested to know the answer. Maybe it could be reworded to something along the lines of "What use could I have for an invalid GIF on my site?" and just give Google as an example.

Comment: @user1291332 This just becomes too broad then. I think a question like this isn't on-topic at any SE site. [Chat] is probably the best place for it.

Comment: @gronostaj It's hard to tell without seeing the actual code, but maybe it's for tracking purposes and visibility would be undesirable. Regarding the Meta question you referenced, if you see the second bullet point under _What shouldn't I ask here?_, questions about other sites are off-topic. I appreciate your point about the Help Center though, which is why I proposed changes to it in this Meta question: [There are a lot of questions being put on hold on a daily basis](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1241/there-are-a-lot-of-questions-being-put-on-hold-on-a-daily-basis).

Comment: @dan It could be for tracking if it was pulled from the server, but it's embedded in base64. That's why I'm curious what it does.

Comment: @gronostaj I see, it wasn't clear without the code quoted. I don't think it would work as a spacer either if it's not visible... Maybe you could ask this over at [Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/en).